# Fetch Exceptions from logs along with stacktrace

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to fetch exceptions from the logs along with StackTrace.
The logs are in the format given below.

```
[2015-01-07 18:39:18,212] host123 WARN com.host123 .elf.UserQuest - Quest/option {o.q.more.paper.osc#0} references unknown dependent {t.what.form.file.more.action} in application {src-code}. Please revise.
[2015-01-07 18:39:18,212] host123 WARN com.host123 .elf.UserQuest - Quest/option {o.q.more.paper.osc#1} references unknown dependent {t.what.form.file.more.action} in application {src-code}. Please revise.
[2015-01-07 18:40:34,281] cessor32 ERROR com.host123 .email.DirectMailer - Unable to connect to server {1.1.1.1}:
       javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 1.1.1.1, port: 25, response: 451
       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:996)
       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:197)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:233)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
       at com.host123.email.DirectMailer.deliverMessage(DirectMailer.java:191)
       at com.host123.email.DirectMailer.send(DirectMailer.java:153)
       at com.host123.webface.util.Notifications.sendEmailX(Notifications.java:126)
       at com.host123.webface.util.Notifications.sendEmail(Notifications.java:91)
       at com.host123.webface.util.Notifications.sendEmail(Notifications.java:145)
       at com.host123.edp.webface.action.DocRecoveryActionProcessor.perform(DocRecoveryActionProcessor.java:81 )
```

I am using this code to fetch the records

```
sed -n '/${bb}/,/${aa}/p' ${k}|egrep "ERROR|ORA|Exception|at.*\.java\:.*"
```

where bb is the previous date and aa is the current date.
If I use only sed command than I am able to fetch the details based on date condition but using egrep along with sed gives no output.

I also tried using awk command.

```
awk -v "sd=$aa" -v "ed=$bb" -F "," '$1 >= sd && $1 <= ed' $k
```

What I think might be the problem is that awk command fetches the line which have date in it and StackTrace row does not have any row. It might or might not be correct.

Also I am fetching this from thousands of log files If there is any way to reduce the amount of memory used for fetched data will be very useful.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $1 is `[2015-01-07 18:39:18` with the `[` .

Comment: Provide sample values of `$bb` and `$aa` with your expected output.

Comment: if you know the default length of your stack traces you could probably use something like `grep Exception -B 1 -A TraceLength-1`

Comment: bb = [2015-01-07 18:39:18 same thing with aa.

Comment: escape the `[` like this `\[`

Comment: Show the expected output you want given that sample input and with the exact values of aa and bb you would use to get that output from that input. This is a trivial job for awk but we can't tell you the exact command to run until you tell us exactly what you want the output to be and how you want to select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
besc="\\${bb}";aesc="\\${aa}"

sed -n "/${besc}/,/${aesc}/ {
   /\\(ERROR\\)|\\(ORA\\)|\\(Exception\\)|\(at.*\\.java\\:.*\\)/ p
   }" ${k}
```

- escape the `[` (or dont use it)
- normaly no need of egrep, sed could take this also in a sub process

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[^[:blank:]]/ {
    dt = $1 " " $2
    found = ( ((sd=="")||(dt>=sd)) && ((ed=="")||(dt<=ed)) )
}
found

$ awk -v sd='[2015-01-07 18:40:34,281]' -f tst.awk file
[2015-01-07 18:40:34,281] cessor32 ERROR com.host123 .email.DirectMailer - Unable to connect to server {1.1.1.1}:
       javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 1.1.1.1, port: 25, response: 451
       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:996)
       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:197)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:233)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
       at com.host123.email.DirectMailer.deliverMessage(DirectMailer.java:191)
       at com.host123.email.DirectMailer.send(DirectMailer.java:153)
       at com.host123.webface.util.Notifications.sendEmailX(Notifications.java:126)
       at com.host123.webface.util.Notifications.sendEmail(Notifications.java:91)
       at com.host123.webface.util.Notifications.sendEmail(Notifications.java:145)
       at com.host123.edp.webface.action.DocRecoveryActionProcessor.perform(DocRecoveryActionProcessor.java:81 )
```

If you don't specify `sd` it starts at the beginning of the file and if you don't specify `ed` it goes to the end of the file. If you specify both youll get the records within that range, inclusive.

I've no idea what the purpose for `egrep "ERROR|ORA|Exception|at.*\.java\:.*"` is in your question - if it has a purpose please update your question to clarify with specific sample input and output showing what it is for and I'll update this answer with whatever trivial tweak is needed to do whatever it is you want.

Comment: egrep is used to fetch any exceptions occurring in the log.

Comment: You're missing my point. "any exceptions occurring in the log" means something to YOU but it means absolutely nothing to ME. Update your question to SHOW what you mean in terms of lines in your input file and fields within those lines, with good sample input and expected output. It's all just specific values in specific rows and columns to me - I don't know or care what an "exception" is.